# Flutter appBar: how to make appBar overflow to popup menu?

Tags: flutter, appbar

Flutter appBar:

```
 Scaffold(
   appBar : AppBar(
      actions: [IconButton1 IconButton2 ... IconButtonN]
   ), 
   body:
 );


 IconButton1 IconButton2 ... IconButtonN
```

In a narrow screen, the list of icon buttons will overflow. How to make the list of overflowed buttons into a popup menu automatically?

```
 IconButton1 IconButton2 PopupMenuButton
                         Item1
                         Item2
                          ...
                         ItemN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` to get the device width and conditionally render the icon buttons directly, or create a `PopupMenuButton` that displays the icon buttons in a popup menu.

Like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IconButtonsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<IconButton> iconButtons = [
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.home), onPressed: () {}),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {}),
    // ... add more icon buttons
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Icon Buttons'),
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          if (screenWidth > 600) // Set your desired breakpoint
            ...iconButtons,
          if (screenWidth <= 600)
            PopupMenuButton<String>(
              icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                return iconButtons.map((IconButton button) {
                  return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                    value: 'menuItem',
                    child: button.icon,
                  );
                }).toList();
              },
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to figure out how many icons the appBar can hold? and put the rest into the popup menu.

Comment: You can measure the average width of a single icon, and divide the AppBar's width by that average width to get an approximate number of icons that can fit. For example, if the average width of a single icon is 40 pixels, and the AppBar has a width of 400 pixels, then approximately 10 icons will fit.

Comment: In Dart you can use `~/` to get divide, returning an integer result.